# django css works on chrome but not firefox

Tags: python, css, django, html

I'm developing django website and am using bootstrap, I can see the styles on chrome browser but not firefox.

firefox inspection shows 404 error for the bootstrap and chrome doesn't. Thankful for any idea.

Code :-

```
#settings.py 

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '%s/coffestatic/' % (BASE_DIR)

STATICFILES_DIRS = ['%s/website-static-default/'% (BASE_DIR),
                     ("bootstrap", '%s/bootstrap' % (BASE_DIR)),]
```

## HTTP file.html

```
<head>
{% load static %}

<link href="{% static'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'%}"rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

## Files structure

BASEDIR

`|--ProjectFolder`

`|------Apps`

`|--BootstrapDir`

`|------css`

## Work flow

- Define static files
- python manage.py collectstatic
- Define styles in html
- run project

Thanks

Comment: Django itself doesn't care whether the client is chrome or firefox or just whatever so I fail to see how the same url would yield a 200 with one client and a 404 with another. Please make sure you've cleared your browser's caches, and do a test with a command-line client that doesn't use any cache (ie with python-requests).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your settings.py files are correct as they are different from how I would set things up. That being said, I'm no expert and you may well be running a different version of django to me.  What I did notice though is you don't have a file type on your link file.  Maybe Chrome is fine without this but maybe Firefox is having a hissy fit without it.  Try changing:

```
<link href="{% static'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'%}"rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="{% static'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'%}"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Just a guess....

Comment: I have tried it but didn't work. The thing is I need to know why it gives 404, this is what I get :-  ( Request URL: http://localhost:8000/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css / 404 Not Found ) in the inspection but google doesn't do it, Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap starter file in your html file will help; as I have done the same and it helped.
Add these files at the end in body section:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRS
```

and add these files at the starting in head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I'm a beginner at django so not sure about it but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In project folder create a directory with any name. Let's name `__shared__` and put the css and jss folders inside the directory

and in settings.py 
at bottom put this code

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "__shared__"),
]
```